# Post multiple images using SLComposeViewController on Facebook/ Twitter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

I am an iOS developer and I am currently using SLComposeViewController to share a post on Facebook/Twitter. My issue is that I have to post multiple images in a single post.

I have done this as follows:

```
SLComposeViewController* mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:textTobeShared];
mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://click-labs.com/"]];
for(int count=0;count<imageArray.count;count++)
        if([mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray objectAtIndex:count]]])
```

In the above code, imageArray is the array of images that I want to post.

When I am doing this on Facebook, all the images are posted as a separate post.

While in case of Twitter, **addImage** method returns true only for the first images while in case of other images it returns false. So only one image is posted.

So I want to know how to achieve my goal and is it possible to post multiple images in  a single tweet.

Comment: In twitter you can only post one image per tweet. There is no such thing as an album in twitter.

Comment: are you sure there is no way to achieve this in twitter. Is there any documentation regarding this issue available.

Comment: If you are a twitter user then you will know this. Each tweet(post in other term) will have a single picture associated to it.

Comment: Actually I am new to twitter so I have no idea about it.

Comment: @girish_vr check this Twitter blog post. It should be already possible. https://blog.twitter.com/2014/photos-just-got-more-social

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an album first.

Here's a [link to the facebook album API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album) documentation.

```
- (void)shareToFacebook {
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    NSLog(@"SESSION IS OPEN");

    [self createFacebookAlbum];
} else {
    NSLog(@"SESSION IS NOT OPEN");
    NSArray* permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

        if (error) {
            /* handle failure */
            NSLog(@"error:%@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was a problem with your Facebook permissions." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed ) {
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        }
        else if (state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended || state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
            if(!self.presentedFacebookSheet) {
                [self performSelector:@selector(reauthorizeAndContinuePostToFacebook) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
                self.presentedFacebookSheet = YES;
            }
        }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)reauthorizeAndContinuePostToFacebook {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];

    [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        [self shareToFacebook];
    }];
}

- (void)createFacebookAlbum {
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setObject:@"Test name" forKey:@"name"];
    [parameters setObject:@"Test message" forKey:@"message"];

    FBRequest* request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSLog(@"creating facebook album");
    FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [connection addRequest:request
         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString* albumId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                 NSLog(@"OK %@", albumId);
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.userInfo);
             }
         }];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
        {
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
               NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     //error
                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"User session found");
                 }
             }];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible using SLComposeViewController to do the same thing

Comment: Funny, in this post the problem/requirement is totally opposite.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514179/facebook-ios6-integration-adds-image-to-album-and-not-separate-posts

Comment: Yes, I have just now seen the question. But it is in the case of single image post.